# How to write bots that runs on ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, bots

I need to get data from a website. But this website doesn't have an api. Therefore I need to write a bot that can use the search text field and get URL of links. How can I write a bot that can run on iOS with swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the html profiles from the URL links, and write regular expressions to parse the html profiles. 
You do not need to write a bot. But you may get incomplete html data from normal request, because these websites block the requests other than browsers. If this, you can edit the http header to cheat the website that you really visit by browser.